# Accept Rate Not Shown

Tags: discussion

Why isn't the acceptance rate not shown on Web Applications, as it is on SO:

[image: screen shot]

Comment: It seemed that everybody was having none....

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Starting today, [the accept rate is no longer shown](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/164654/133693):

> Starting with the next build accept rate will no longer be shown. We're still keeping track of it on the backend for various things, but the negative behavior its display encourages outweighs its benefits.

---

<s>[This blog post](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/08/new-question-asker-features/) explains when accept rate is shown</s>

> Below **the question owner** signature block, for non-community-wiki
>   questions, we show the percent of accepted answers for that user. It
>   won’t always appear, though. The following rules are used in the
>   calculation:
>
> - Questions must not be community wiki.
> - Questions must not be closed.
> - Questions must be more than 3 days old.
> - Questions must have at least 1 answer.
> - There must be at least four eligible questions as determined by the above rules, otherwise the statistic will not appear.